# Confused about 2D arrays in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm having problems with creating a 2D boolean array in C++. I wrote a quick program for create and print all the bool array.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    const int WIDTH = 20;
    const int HEIGHT = 20;

    bool world [HEIGHT][WIDTH];

    for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++){
            world[i][j] = true;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++){
            if(world[i][j]){
                cout << j;
            }else{
                cout << ' ';
            };
        }
        cout << "-" << i << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

And this is his output.

```
012345678910111213141516171819-0
012345678910111213141516171819-1
012345678910111213141516171819-2
012345678910111213141516171819-3
012345678910111213141516171819-4
012345678910111213141516171819-5
012345678910111213141516171819-6
012345678910111213141516171819-7
012345678910111213141516171819-8
012345678910111213141516171819-9
012345678910111213141516171819-10
012345678910111213141516171819-11
012345678910111213141516171819-12
012345678910111213141516171819-13
012345678910111213141516171819-14
012345678910111213141516171819-15
012345678910111213141516171819-16
012345678910111213141516171819-17
012345678910111213141516171819-18
012345678910111213141516171819-19
```

It creates a 2D array, set all his values to true, and print the array. This is fine, the problem is when the 2d array get bigger. For example if I change the size of WIDTH and HEIGHT to 30, when i print the array I have the following ouput:

```
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-0
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-1
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-2
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-3
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-4
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-5
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-6
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-7
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-8
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-9
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-10
01234567891011121314151617181920212201234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-11
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-12
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-13
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-14
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-15
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-16
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-17
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-18
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-19
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-20
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-21
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-22
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-23
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-24
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-25
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-26
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-27
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-28
01234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829-29
```

As you can see on the line 11 it counts until 22 and restart the for loop for j. I don't know what is wrong, I need an 2D array of bools of size [50][50] but I don't what is wrong there.

**EDIT: The problem is the compiler. I tried the same code on GCC compiler on a Linux machine and works perfectly. This code works fine, the problem is the compiler or the compiler with the CLion IDE. It compiles but I have problems with the running or the output produced. The code works fine with GCC compiler or on an Unix machine**

Comment: Although that might not be the cause of your current problems, consider avoiding allocating large arrays on the stack.

Comment: It is not harmful for now because `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` are same, but in `world[i][j]`, `i` can only be upto `WIDTH-1`, not `HEIGHT-1`.

Comment: Hmmm, [coundl't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Tf8pVcaRLEtyqT3V).

Comment: @MikeCAT that is weird, i tried that link and is printing all the values right. $: Maybe the proble is the IDE that I am using (CLion)? I'm going to test this program on Visual Studio and see what is happend

Comment: What is the compielr?

Comment: I'm using MinGw 3.21. CMake 3.3.2 (I know is not a compiler). And debugger GDB 7.8

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that is NOT working.  You do not need to include the code or the output from the version that did work.  We can only debug code you post, not code you describe. Also, please make very sure that the code in the question is exactly the same as the code you are running in your compiler that gives the bogus output.

Answer (score 2):

Okay this is logically absolutely correct and i have tested your code on online compiler using 20 as well as 30. restart your compiler or try another compiler a reliable one... Here is the screenshot of your result when i executed your code online.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
bool world [WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

Should be

```
bool world [HEIGHT][WIDTH];
```

As the `i` in your loop ranges from `0` to `HEIGHT-1`. `j` ranges from `0` to `WIDTH-1`

Comment: it was my fault when i wrote this quick test program. In this case does not matter, because both have the same value